# ESLint/prettier conflict when using cumulusci namespace placeholder in Apex

Tags: apex, cumulusci, eslint, prettier

I am getting the below error when I run `npm run prettier` and when I commit (since I have a husky hook) a couple of Apex classes that use namespace placeholders .

`Error: Found punctuation symbol or operator '%' that isn't valid in Apex.`

I tried telling prettier and eslint to ignore these lines of code but I keep getting the same errors. Example:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line prettier-ignore
System.assertEquals('3/30/2015', 
   %%%NAMESPACE_DOT%%%DateUtils.formatDate(firstMonday('3/30/2015'), 'M/d/yyyy'));
```

Comment: Why do you need `%%%NAMESPACE_DOT%%%`? Under normal circumstances, you don't need to worry about namespaces in Apex. I'd say there's more a problem with your packaging strategy.

Comment: I have an unlocked package that depends on another unlocked package. They share the same namespace. I am deploying to both namespaced orgs and persistent orgs... Now that you mention it, I don't necessarily have to use namespace placeholders in my packaged code... I do need it in my unpackaged code. Thanks for the pointer :)